# How can I randomly sample binomial thing?

Tags: r, simulation, binomial-coefficients

For example,
I want to randomly line the 0, 1 (50% respectively) 10 times.
So, there should be five  "0" and five "1".

But, when I used:

```r
rbinom(10,1,0.5)
```

sometimes, it generates four "0" and six "1".

I noticed that the `sample()` function has also this issue.

There should be five "0" and five "1", and the order should be at random.

Comment: What you are asking for is a permutation, not the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sample` will shuffle a vector randomly.  So  `sample(rep(c(0,1),5))` is what you need.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `sample()`, but this way:

```
b <- c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5))
sample(b)
#  [1] 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
sample(b)
#  [1] 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
sample(b)
#  [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
sample(b)
#  [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 3):

A shortcut would be:

```r
sample(10) %/% 6
#> [1] 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `bitwAnd` + `sample`

```
bitwAnd(sample(10), 1)
```